# How to wait for correct element to be inserted ?(webscrape)

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have been trying to extract data from a flight website. Give an example, the first 5 flights appeared usually do not have layover. However, the flights after the first 5 flights have layover. The results for the layover of the (flights after the first five flights) were shown in the (first five flights) because the (first five flights) do not have element in the HTML ( i checked!).

```
layovers = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@data-test-id='layover-airport-stops']")
layovers_list = [value.text for value in layovers]
```

then i did this

```
try:
    df.loc[i, 'layovers'] = layovers_list[i]
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

is it because i pass the exception?
I wanted to try using the code to wait the correct elements, but not too familiar with it. please help!

Comment: can you post the flight website url?

Comment: link = 'https://www.expedia.com/Flights-Search?trip=multi&leg1=from%3ALondon%2C%20England%2C%20UK%20(LON)%2Cto%3ABarcelona%2C%20Spain%20(BCN)%2Cdeparture%3A08%2F03%2F2020TANYT&leg2=from%3ABarcelona%2C%20Spain%20(BCN-All%20Airports)%2Cto%3ALondon%2C%20England%2C%20UK%20(LHR-Heathrow)%2Cdeparture%3A08%2F15%2F2020TANYT&passengers=adults%3A1%2Cchildren%3A0%2Cseniors%3A0%2Cinfantinlap%3AY&options=cabinclass%3Aeconomy&mode=search&origref=www.expedia.com'

Comment: You can pass the empty or null value if the layover element is not there. Can you post your expected result Vs what is actually you are getting. Also if you can post the complete code that would help us to provide a quick solution.